# IdentityServer3 FB or GOOGLE+ login how to get UserInfo and access token for FB or GOOGLE+

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-api, identityserver3

Here is nice tutorial for IdentityServer3 and GOOGLE+ login is included

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html

```
var google = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Google",
                Caption = "Google",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,

                ClientId = "xxxxx-8boio83mb57ruogr9af9ut09fkg56b27.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                ClientSecret = "5fWcBT0udKY7_b6E3gEiJlze"
            };
            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(google);

var fb = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Facebook",
                Caption = "Facebook",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,

                AppId = "xxxxxxx",
                AppSecret = "9d6ab75f921942e61fb43a9b1fc25c63"
            };
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fb);
```

Problem is when I click on GOOGLE+ I get back access token but this token is not valid for google api. I can't to get token back which will be valid for Google+ API so that i can get all UserData back.

Same problem with FB

Is this possible?

Comment: you are missing scopes that's what defines which api you are requesting access for.    That's one really long tutorial you found there.

Comment: I am using openid and profile scope. Which one is then important? I also tried with public_profile.

Comment: if you want to access the google+ API then you have to use the scope for the google+ API.   Scopes tell the user authenticating your application that you want access to.  If you want access to there Google+ account you have to tell them that, and enable it in the google developers console.

Comment: As is written here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth scope "profile" should be enough but still does not work

Comment: then what's the problem?  What request are you sending to the Google+ API and what error is it returning?

Comment: What about getting friends or user profile picture. With IdentityServer3 and scopes is not possible...